# Search custom Refinement

Tags: 2013, search, refinement-panel

I watched Matthew McDermott's video ([SharePoint Conference)](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/SharePoint-Conference/2014/SPC322) and I really like those custom refiners:

[image]

How is it possible to get the refinement items **next to each other (horizonally) instead of vertically**? **Are the files anywhere available**?

I have by now the following (my refiners, but all vertically):

[image]

**The files** would be great how this is done, or at least the way how to get the refiners **next to each other**.

Comment: please tell me, why this question was downvoted!?

Comment: May be because the question is not very clear at first sight. You can re write your question in a well described way. And some more focus on what you want..

Comment: Tried to rewrite my question. Looking for the .html files with the code from Matthew or the code how to get the Partner Level "Bronze", "Silver" and "Gold" next to each other with colors or badges

Comment: There are so many pundits who are always ready to down-vote with their knives but never bother to comment. I have a favorite quote for them **Knives in donkeys hand**.

Comment: Is the question now clear? Sorry, my english is not the best, but I thought it is quite clear...

Comment: If it is not clear to anyone then he/she should comment before/after using their knives (down-voting).

Comment: It's a valuable question and very clear!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's just CSS. Here is the snippet showing the inline style. I use inline-block rather than float as it gave me the organization and flow I needed for the wrapper divs. Let me know if you want the whole file and I'll post it for you.

```
<div id='Value' name='Item' style="width:25px;height:25px;border-radius:3px;display:inline-block;">
  <a id='FilterLink' class='_#= $htmlEncode(aClass) =#_' onclick="_#= aOnClick =#_" href='javascript:{}' title='_#= $htmlEncode(String.format(Srch.U.loadResource("rf_RefineBy"), refinementName)) =#_'>
    <!--#_
    if (refinementName == 'All')
    {
    _#-->
    <div id='RefinementName' style="background-color:aquamarine;width:75px;height:25px;border-radius:3px;display:inline-block;padding:0px 4px;text-align:center;">Clear Filter</div>
    <!--#_
    } 
    else 
    {
    _#-->
    <div id='RefinementName' style="display:inline-block;">
        <img src="_#= iconFile =#_" alt="refine by: _#= refinementName =#_"/>
    </div>
```

Comment: Can some more context be given? I am not using anything special just want the OOTB refiner to be laid out horizontally. I have no idea where this code would even go since I'm not literally editing static divs on a page.

Comment: @Bruce, this is a display template. If you are unfamiliar with them check this 101 post. http://www.ableblue.com/blog/archive/2013/06/05/introduction-to-sharepoint-2013-display-templates/

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that I understood you correctly. But this loos like a simple CSS issue in your refinement file (normaly at '/Display Templates/Filters'). Look at the CSS float property:
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_float.asp

```
<div style="float: left;">
    <optgroup label="Selected Refiners" id="_#= refinement1 =#_">
        //your refinement stuff here
    </optgroup>
</div>

<div>
    <optgroup label="Other Refiners" id="_#= refinement2 =#_">
        //your other refinement stuff here
    </optgroup>
<div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a "control" template for refiners that specifies how they are laid out. The "out of the box" one is control_refinement.html and is in /_catalogs/masterpage/DisplayTemplates/Filters. If you look at it you'll notice it's title is "Vertical".

To get the refiners displayed horizontally, you should create your own control template (possibly copying the existing one as a starting point), and then edit the HTML to display the refiners as you need.

Then in the refiner web part's properties, you'll see there's a "Control" dropdown which has the "Vertical" template selected by default, just change this to your new template.